# Why can some people not reproduce this Python security issue?

Tags: python, ubuntu, security, debian

I stumbled across this interesting Python security issue recently:

https://twitter.com/marekgibney/status/1598706464583028736

I can reproduce it in Debian 11 and in Ubuntu 22.04

But about 50% of people can't. How is their setup different? Even after some discussion, so far, nobody figured it out.

Here is a way to reproduce it in Docker:

```
docker run --rm -it debian:11
apt update -y && apt upgrade -y
apt install -y python3
python3 -m pydoc csv # <= Shows the python documentation for csv
echo 'print("P0wned");exit()' > collections.py
python3 -m pydoc csv # <= Shows "P0wned"
```

Comment: I have played with it and it did work on my side. Why it does not work for some? I have some guesses one involving docker not being installed. ;)

Comment: @MarekPuchalski It's not that people cannot reproduce it in Docker. But some cannot reproduce it on their native OS. I wonder how their setup is different. Does their version of pydoc not use collections.py? Is their precedence of import paths different?

Comment: Didn't work in LM ulyssa.